# The uploaded Jupyter notebook to GitHub does not show folium map

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, folium

I have a Jupyter notebook which has codes to process folium maps and when I uploaded this notebook to GitHub, it does not show the interactive map. Does anybody know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: !conda install -c conda-forge folium=0.5.0 --yes 
import folium # map rendering library
lat=43.653963
long=-79.387207

map_Toronto = folium.Map(location=[lat, long], zoom_start=10)
map_Toronto

Comment: This is my python code. I uploaded the file containing this code to Github and but it does not  show the map.

Comment: Please add code in question.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, folium maps don't show up in github.  You could check out https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/

Comment: Please be specific what you mean with *"it does not show the interactive map"*. Where? Clicking on what?